# web services. Are they deprecated?

Tags: iphone

I have always been a client server developer.  I am getting into mobile development.  Are web services not used in mobile environment?  We used SOAP and POST/GET web services in .NET for our applications.  What is the equivalent in iphone?  What should I be reading. My objective is something like social networking on an ipad.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello You can use SOAP or POST or GET, All of this webservices are being used in iPhone..
just there is the difference of implementation in Code side.. and You have to request a URL and Pass the Input Parameters... and You will have a response and the response can be anything XML or JSON.. and the parsing methods are different only..

You can make SOAP request using this [Link](http://www.makebetterthings.com/blogs/iphone/call-soap-web-service-from-iphone/) ...Please Find It...

Hope It will help You...

Comment: Fine I am good here.But I think it is better to use Rest Web Services means your POST,GET,UPDATE or DELETE rather than using SOAP based web services.The main reason to use this type is that they simply provide solution rather then SOAP web services in which you have to pass hard coded xml's as request & then parse the xml response.But in RESTful services you simply call it & get the response..Net is based for the RESTful Web services.Use can watch this link for reference http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39119/Consuming-a-RESTful-Service-bit-ly-in-an-iPhone-Ap.aspx

Answer (score 2):

of course you can use web services just like you used in .Net. Just request a url and pass parameter and you will have response. So you can call/use web services from Mobile apps too. You can visit **[this blog](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/)** for more information.